# Cannot send data to my server using AsyncHttpClient (String Variables aren't passed)

Tags: java, android, class, variables, android-asynctask

I am a newbie in android development (and programming in general) and I am using  android development to teach myself how to program (that's how I learn); so I am currently working on a program that receives 4 different data inputs from the user and sends it over via HTTP post request to my local raspberry pi. 
Two of the inputs come from spinners, and they're just integers, the other two come from an `EditText` block which just receives numbers as inputs, though I used strings to get the data from the `EditText`. Find summary of code mentioned above, below.

```
//From MainActivity class and file.
    public static int data1;
    public static int data2;
    public static String data3;
    public static String data4;
```

The user then types in the data asked... the variables change (I tested this, by constantly printing them out on Toasts and `TextView`). The variables are set and called from another file and class "`dataProcessingFile`"
This is how I called and set them in the `MainActivity` file.

```
dataProcessingFile dpFob = new dataProcessingFile();
dpFob.setData1(position); //position from the spinner
```

same for all the information just different functions for each, getting the data is also the same - and it works

```
 dpFob.getData1(); /* usually convert it to string for display with  
 String.valueOf(dpFob.getData1()); */
```

Everything works fine until here:  the part where I have to send the data over to my server.
I made another file and class, imported all the libraries I need, no compilation error but when I get the `String` related variables within the main function in this new class they are logged as being empty, even when I display them with `TextView`, still empty; the int releated variables do however show up... here is the coding to that:

```
package com.example.tswelo.myPackageName;

import android.util.Log;

import com.loopj.android.http.*;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.*;

public class SendRequest {


public void runSendRequest()

{
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://192.168.43.20/cgi-bin/index.cgi", new     
    AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        dataProcessingFile secActObj = new dataProcessingFile ();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        @Override
        public void onStart() {

            params.put("PN_VOU",secActObj.getData3() + " " +  
            secActObj.getData4()); // problem arises here
            params.put("UC_AC",secActObj.getData1() + " " + 
            secActObj.getData2());
            Log.e("params",  secActObj.getData3()+ " " +secActObj.getData4()  
            ); // problem arises here, shows nothing, just an empty space!
            Log.e("params2", secActObj.getData1() + " " + 
            secActObj.getData2());

        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[]  
response) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] 
    errorResponse, Throwable e) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)

        }

        @Override
        public void onRetry(int retryNo) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

The digit length of data 3 is 12 - 16 numbers, and data 4 is 10 numbers.
When I tried converting them to integers the program crashed! I used
    `Integer.valueOf(getData3());` //  and the same for data4.

Comment: Your question is very long - my first suggestion is that you reduce the question to: "I have a problem sending data to my server and processing responses using AsyncHttpClient". Once you get past this stage, you can post further questions as you learn.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla thanks for the advice, appreciate it.

Comment: @ Super-califragilistic Nop, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

have a look in your SendRequest class

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://192.168.43.20/cgi-bin/index.cgi", new     
AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    dataProcessingFile secActObj = new dataProcessingFile ();
  //dataProcessingFile has been initialized. everything is empty in it
```

i think inject dataProcessingFile object into your class like this

```
public class SendRequest {
   private dataProcessingFile  secActObj;
   public SendRequest(dataProcessingFile  a){
         secActObj = a;
  ....
```

in your sendRequest method

```
public void runSendRequest() {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://192.168.43.20/cgi-bin/index.cgi", new     
AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    dataProcessingFile secActObj = new dataProcessingFile ();//now remove this
```

That will do